# Assigning values of a range to an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I have write bellow code, that prints `210` in immediate window.

```
Sub RangeToArr()
    Dim data() As Variant
    data = Range("Salary[EmpNum]").Value
    Debug.Print UBound(data)
End Sub
```

When I using bellow, the `Subscript out of range` Run-time error message will displayed.

```
Sub RangeToArr()
    Dim data() As Variant
    data = Range("Salary[EmpNum]").Value
    Debug.Print data(210)
End Sub
```

If `data` is an array, what is the problem, else, how can access a range values that assigned to an array, as above?

Comment: Also check the scope of data in the locals window with a breakpoint, is it only a single dimension? even a column's data could be scoped as (1 to 210, 1 to 1). Looking further at this, and assuming you want data to represent the range, drop the `.Value` part from the assignment line.

Comment: Above range , is a column of a filtered Table range. The scope is 6 to 215

Comment: What is `Salary[EmpNum]`?

Comment: `Salary` is name of a table object and `EmpNum` is heading of the one of its column.

Comment: A range converted to an array will create a 2 dimensional array, when you try to return data(210) you are referencing it as if it's a single dimensional array. What happens if you try returning data(210, 1)? (Edit:- I originally put data(20, 0) forgetting that a range converts to an array in base 1)

Comment: Please present and extend your answer.

Comment: Whenever an array is created using range of cells then array created will always be a two dimensional array. This is because a spreadsheet stores values in two dimensions i.e. rows and columns. So the first dimension is the rows and the second dimension is the columns. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45937609/6075259).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A range converted to an array will create a 2 dimensional array, if you try to return data(210) you are referencing it as if it's a single dimensional array. You can get the value from the 210th cell in the range by returning

```
data(210, 1)
```

I can only assume as to the reason why it forces a 2 dimensional array. My guess is because if your range included additional columns it would be 2 dimensional array. The act of creating a 2 dimensional array regardless even if you only have one column means the method for dealing with the data remains the same. There is an exception to this - If your range is a single cell, VBA will populate just the value as a single dimension.

Comment: If Salary[EmpNum] is a single column the array size should be data(1 to 210, 1). I don't mind correcting my answer if it's wrong, but I would need to understand what is wrong in my assumption so I can update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure your sample works, make sure you have 210 rows in your table sample.

---

In general, try something like this to get the idea of the arrays and ranges:

- Crate a simple named range `MyNamedRange` with more than one column and more than one row
- Put some values in it
- Run this and see what you are getting in the immediate window:

---

```
Sub RangeToArr()

    Dim arrVar  As Variant
    arrVar = Range("MyNamedRange")
    Debug.Print arrVar(1, 2)

End Sub
```

Change the `(1,2)` values a bit to get the idea.